# Triangle distribution ifelse statement

Tags: r

I am trying to make my own function of the triangle distribution that should return the probability, similar to the one in triangle package. The problem I have is how to incorporate the if statement of lower.tail (that should compute the lower tail) and log.p (that should compute the logarithm of the density). Is there anyone who knows how to solve this?

Thanks.

The function I have:

```
ptriangle3 <- function(q, a, b, c, lower.tail = T, log.p = F){
  if (!all(a <= c && c <= b && a < b)) stop("Villkoren måste uppfyllas: a <= c <= b and a < b!")
  
  ifelse(q > a & q < b,
         ifelse(q <= c,
                ((q-a)^2)/((b-a)*(c-a)),
                1-((b-q)^2)/((b-a)*(b-c))),
         ifelse(q <= a,
                0,
                1))
  
}
```

Comment: You could use dplyr::case_when() to avoid nested ifelse() functions.

Comment: Assign the value of `ifelse` to a variable, `p<-ifelse(...)` and then use `if(!lower.tail) p <- 1-p` and `if(log.p) p <- log(p)`. Then return `p`.

Comment: @BillO'Brien You should avoid `dplyr` unless absolutely necessary...

Comment: I wouldn't want to use dplyr as well but instead write the code this way as Rui instructed.

`ptriangle <- function(q, a, b, c, lower.tail=T,  log.p = F){
  if (!all(a <= c && c <= b && a < b)) stop("Villkoren måste uppfyllas: a <= c <= b and a < b!")
  
  p <- ifelse(q > a & q < b,
              ifelse(q <= c,
                     f <- ((q-a)^2)/((b-a)*(c-a)),
                     f <- 1-((b-q)^2)/((b-a)*(b-c))),
              ifelse(q <= a,
                     f <- 0,
                     f <- 1))
  
  if(!lower.tail) p <- 1-p
  if(log.p) p <- log(p)
  return(p)
  
}`

Comment: @algae The case_when() function is a better implementation of testing for multiple conditions compared with base R ifelse(). While I prefer base R functions in most cases, reflexively avoiding dplyr is naive.